# What is a nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am running through some examples of '**nested for loops**' and the below code is given as an example. But isn't this technically a *for* loop?

```
xLimits = range(getWidth(pic))
for x in xLimits:
    pixel = getPixelAt(pic, x, 0)
    setColor(pixel, green)
```

Wouldn't a nested look something like this?

```
for x in xLimits:
    for y in yLimits:
        code
        code
        code
```

Can someone either agree or disagree with me?

I know this probably doesn't matter but if I am not looking at this the right way I would like to know why.

Comment: It's possible that the implementation of `getPixelAt` itself has a for loop, and the example was making the point that this hidden for loop is nested inside the outer one, with the same algorithmic implications (quadratic or O(NM) time instead of linear). But it's also possible that the author screwed up, or is just an idiot. You'd have to tell us where the example came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested loop (of any kind) is a loop within a loop. It's important to realize that the inner loop will be re-run for *every* iteration of the outer loop.

For example:

```
for i in xrange(3):
    for j in xrange(2):
        print 'i={0} j={1}'.format(i,j)
```

Output:

```
i=0 j=0    
i=0 j=1
i=1 j=0    <-- inner loop restarts
i=1 j=1
i=2 j=0    <-- inner loop restarts
i=2 j=1
```

So your understanding is totally correct. The first example is not a nested loop, while the second example is.

You could *possibly* consider calling a function with a `for` loop, from within a `for` loop, a "nested for loop", although I would never call it that:

```
def foo(r):
    for i in r:
        do_something()

for x in xrange(20):
    foo( xrange(x) )
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested for loop is a for loop inside another for loop, as you think. The first example you gave is not a nested for loop, but the second one is.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom example is a nested for loop as you said. I would guess that the author of the information knows something more about the other two called functions [getPixelAt() or setColor(,)] that constitutes them as for loops thus making the example nested, at least from an efficiency (Big O) standpoint.